# How to skip a class with public access to a function?

Tags: c++

I have this setup:

```
class A
{
  public:
  virtual void Function();
}

class B : private A
{

}

class C : public B
{
public:
// I want to expose A::Function() here
}
```

I tried to do this by adding:

```
class C : public B
{
public:
  virtual void Function();
}
```

and

```
C::Function()
{
  A::Function();
}
```

but I get and "inaccessible base" error.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `B` you can change the accessibility of `A::Function` to `protected`:

```
class B : private A
{
protected:
    using A::Function;
};
```

In `C::Function` (and elsewhere in `C`) you will then have to refer to the function as `B::Function`, not `A::Function`.  You could also `public: using B::Function;` in `C` instead of implementing a `C::Function` that just calls `B::Function`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. The fact that `B` inherits from `A` is an implementation detail and you are not allowed to access it from `C`- just like you can't access `B`'s private functions or member variables.

This would be completely legal if `B` inherited `protected` or `public` from A.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change it to `class B : protected A` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The scenario you're describing would indicate that your class hierarchy needs to be reworked.